# Is it enough to declare destructor virtual?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

When I have a class that requires a virtual destructor is it enough to declare it virtual (and let the compiler generate the definition) or do I have to define it explicitly?

Comment: The compiler-generated definition will never be virtual. If you declare a destructor, the compiler simply won't define one.

Comment: Then I guess you should make that an answer?

Comment: [`virtual ~Foo() = default;`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca639bb3d749f4a2) ?

Comment: You're absolutely right, Borgleader, but that works only in C++11.

Comment: @chris: The compiler-generated dtor will be `virtual`... if at least one base-class one was.

Comment: Try just declaring one and see what the linker has to say about it. :)

Comment: In a class definition you should declare and define the destuctor `virtual ~T() {}`, unless you want each derived class having it's own destructor implementation: `virtual ~T() = 0`.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Better explicit defaulting like Borgleader shows, as we want our destructor to stay trivial if possible.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Good point, I was thinking of just within the same class.

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler generates a destructor for you:

> §12.4/4 If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared
>   destructor is an inline public member of its class.

Note that you can do:

```
virtual ~Struct() = default;
```

> 6 Otherwise, the destructor is non-trivial. A destructor that is
>   defaulted and not defined as deleted is implicitly defined when it is
>   odr-used (3.2) to destroy an object of its class type (3.7) or when it
>   is explicitly defaulted after its first declaration.

Or:

```
virtual ~Struct() { }
```

Admittedly, the distinction between "user-declared" and "user-provided" is pretty confusing, so here's the relevant section:

> §8.4.3/4 Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared
>   functions are collectively called *defaulted* functions, and the
>   implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4,
>   12.8), which might mean defining them as deleted. A special member function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided
>   explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its
>   first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly
>   defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the
>   program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly say `virtual ~destructorName()`. Just because you have a derived class does not make the bass class's destructor virtual by default.

Comment: You didn't understand me - I asked if it were enough to declare it (explicitly) virtual or did I have to define it also.